# Please create web server writable folder config in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get phpMyAdmin installed on my Mac El Capitan. Every time I go to:

> http://localhost:8080/phpMyAdmin/setup/

I get the setup page but every time I click "save", I get the following error:

> Please create web server writable folder config in phpMyAdmin top
>   level directory as described in documentation. Otherwise you will be
>   only able to download or display it.

I read other threads on Stackoverflow, and did the following:

1. Created manually a file in my MAMP/htdocs/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php
2. Opened the file and added:

   ```
   $i=0;
   $i++;
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'cbb74bc'; // use here your password
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
   ?>
   ```

(That came from a guide found on the path:
http://localhost:8080/phpMyAdmin/doc/html/setup.html#setup_script
)

This did not solve my problem. I can see around stackoverflow, that this solved the problem for everybody. Does anybody have a clue about what could be wrong here?

Best Regards

**Update after answers**
When I just go to the main folder of the phpadmin I get this error:

[image]

Everything should have read/write access now:

[image]

Comment: The message is asking you to create a folder – so why are you creating a file?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created a folder called 'config', but still the same result.

Comment: And did you verify that folder is writable by the web server?

Comment: I am at the moment just trying to figure out how I do that. I just updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: I reinstalled MAMP, and now it is working without problem

Comment: Great! Nothing like a restart to fix a problem :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please create web server writable **folder** config in phpMyAdmin top level directory as described in documentation. Otherwise you will be only able to download or display it.

From the message, you need to create a **folder** within your root phpMyAdmin directory, named **config**. And it should be writable by your webserver user.

From the [phpMyAdmin docs](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-setup-script):

```
cd phpMyAdmin
mkdir config                        # create directory for saving
chmod o+rw config                   # give it world writable permissions
```

Comment: Hello Mavili, and thank you for your answer. I already did that, but the problem is that I am not quite sure how to test if the folder is writable.

Comment: @NeKr: do a `ls -la` in the root phpmyadmin directory. That'll show your ownership and permissions for the files/folders. Also you'll need to know which user your webserver runs as.

Comment: @NeKr try doing `chmod 775 /path/to/config` and see if you still have the problem. Although your screenshot shows the folder is *read & write*able for everyone, but still worth trying in case it needs execute right

Comment: Alright I got so far now.  I just took a fresh screenshot. I saw that the phpMyAdmin folder only had read access. So I changed that to read and write. Through the terminal I made the config folder, and that also have read/write access now. But yeah, still the same error :-(

Comment: I reinstalled MAMP, and now it is working without problem

Answer (score 1):

Not sure (as I don't use Mac/OSX for servers) but it sounds like you need to change the permissions on the `phpMyAdmin` directory.

Does the web server run as the `www` user? This is the most common. My guess is you need to change either the `owner` and / or the `group` to the `www` user for the `phpMyAdmin` directory. From the command line (in a terminal) on Linux this would be like so:

```
sudo chown -R www:www /full/path/to/phpMyAdmin
```

On OSX, in a terminal you might not need the `sudo` part, so it would be:

```
chown -R www:www /full/path/to/phpMyAdmin
```

On a Mac you can also select the folder then choose the `File` -> `Get info`, then the unlock option and then you can set the `owner` and the `group`.

Hate to link out to another site, but [this article](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415) is pretty clear.

Comment: Hello. I tried to do all the things through the terminal ,and everything should have access now. (Look fresh screenshot). But still the same error

Comment: I reinstalled MAMP, and now it is working without problem

Comment: @NeKr : Is there anything in the `config` folder? If so, should there be on a fresh install? Another option might be to start again :] Simply remove (or rename) the phpMyAdmin directory and start with a fresh version.